# I Want to access function with same name or id and changer their style with javascript

Tags: javascript

This are my options for which text i want to change the style

```
<form id="question29">
<input type="radio" onclick="cbg()" name = "q30" value="A"><div name="ques29">(A) wavelength</div>
<br><input type="radio" onclick="cbg()" name = "q30" value="B"><div name="ques29">(B) frequency</div>
<br><input type="radio" onclick="cbg()" name = "q30" value="C"><div name="ques29">(C) intensity</div>
<br><input type="radio" onclick="cbg()" name = "q30" value="D"><div name="ques29">(D) work function</div>
</form>
```

Now i want to change the color of suppose options (D) work function to green
so how can i do that
well i have defined a class qa to do this

```
.qa {
color:green;
font-size:200%;
}
```

and then i have written this code

```
document.getElementByName("ques29")[1].className = "qa";
```

well i am able to change the color if i assign different names to everyone but unfortunately i need some way to access the options in a format of somename[0] somename[1] somename[2] and somename[3]

any suggestions
thankx in advance

Comment: Firstly it's `getElementsByName()`.. But anyway you've said you need to do exactly what the code you've provided does?

Comment: have you tried changing it to `getElementsByName()`? And are you receiving any error messages?

Comment: okay okay it worked i forgot to change it to getelementsByName()

Comment: well can u tell me a way to do the same thing without the <div> and by only using the radio option or anything using label

Comment: I will post an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `getElementByName()` to `getElementsByName()` (with an 's') to solve the issue of the code not working.

In response to your comment, simply removing the `div`'s and replacing them with `labels`'s should still behave how you want.

**EDIT:**

Your markup should look like this:

```
<form id="question29">
    <input type="radio" onclick="cbg()" name = "q30" value="A"><label name="ques29">(A) wavelength</label>
    <br><input type="radio" onclick="cbg()" name = "q30" value="B"><label name="ques29">(B) frequency</label>
    <br><input type="radio" onclick="cbg()" name = "q30" value="C"><label name="ques29">(C) intensity</label>
    <br><input type="radio" onclick="cbg()" name = "q30" value="D"><label name="ques29">(D) work function</label>
</form>
```

Comment: well its not behaving the same any other suggestions

Comment: Can I see an example of what you've got in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) please?

Comment: You haven't included the index reference after retrieving the named elements: `document.getElementsByName("ques29")[item number you want to change].className = "qa";` **EDIT:** And you've only added one `label` in place of the `div`s

Comment: well but this time there is no index name as there is only one element with that name but anyhow i changed them and it still doesnt work

Comment: Look SO isn't for people to write your code for you! If my answer provided a solution to your problem then great, but if not please don't keep asking about separate issues!